# Generating video sitemap not working quite as expected

Tags: c#, xml-sitemap

OK so I have tried numerous things here but can't get the output right for the element string.

Here is my desired result:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
```

Here is the closest I can get:

```
<urlset xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" />
```

So the attribute strings are back to front(is wrong order).

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteStartElement("urlset", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "video", null, "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1");
```

Additionally I tried using this code from [this example](http://johndyer.name/c-template-for-creating-google-video-sitemap/), but it gives me a error :

```
writer.WriteStartElement("urlset");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "video", null, "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1");
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9' within the same start element tag.

I know I'm missing something here just not sure what, also I looked through google but can't find anything that helps.
I have also tried changing the order of the function variables, just can't make it work right.
Anyone know what's going on?
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("urlset", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "video", null, "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1");
```

Will output:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
```

Here is the full code to output video sitemap, hope it helps someone:

```
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteStartElement("urlset", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "video", null, "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1");

writer.WriteStartElement("url");
writer.WriteElementString("loc", "https://youtube.com");
writer.WriteStartElement("video", "video", "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1");
writer.WriteElementString("video", "thumbnail_loc", null, "https://company.com/image-thumb.jpeg");
writer.WriteElementString("video", "title", null, "this is the video title");
writer.WriteElementString("video", "description", null, "this is a video description");
writer.WriteElementString("video", "content_loc", null, "https://company.com/cool-product");
writer.WriteElementString("video", "family_friendly", null, "yes");
/* Price */
writer.WriteStartElement("video", "price", "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1");
writer.WriteAttributeString("currency", "AUD");
writer.WriteString("100.00");
writer.WriteEndElement();//video:uploader
/* Price */
writer.WriteElementString("video", "requires_subscription", null, "no");
writer.WriteStartElement("video", "uploader", "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1");
writer.WriteAttributeString("info", "https://company.com");
writer.WriteString("My Company");
writer.WriteEndElement();//video:uploader
writer.WriteElementString("video", "live", null, "yes");
writer.WriteEndElement();//video:video
writer.WriteEndElement();//url

writer.WriteEndElement();// urlset
writer.WriteEndDocument();
```

## UPDATE

> I modified the code as the price element needs the currency attribute. It's in between the /* Price */ comments